# Dynamic page (jQuery) not loading javascript correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently writing a small website and just adapted a tutorial found [here](http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/) to get dynamic content loading working. You'll see that on the home page, if you click a link, the view will expand to expose the video beneath it, however if you navigate to the same page using the left sidebar (Top rated) you'll see that all the links are expanded and I can't work out what is going wrong, any ideas?

Website is [here](http://drue.co.uk/1site/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function that collapses the expandable elements (`prepareList`) is only called once - when the DOM is ready.

When you navigate using the sidebar the page doesn't refresh so that function won't be called again.

Add `prepareList()` to the `$mainContent.fadeIn` callback (where you currently have `/* Stop loading animation */`).

Comment: That did the trick, many thanks (I'm fairly new to web development). I put the prepareList() call after this line $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #content", function() { so that the page resized correctly after having prepared (collapsed) the list

Comment: Any ideas about why expanding an element in the list does not move the footer?

Comment: Please create a new question if you need that answered. On first look something is adding a `height` to the `#inside` div.

Comment: Thanks, question posted here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233411/expanding-list-not-moving-container-footer

Answer (score 2):

Your code in scripts.js (line 67):

```
$("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("link2currentpage");
```

results in the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=index.html]
```

You need to put quotes around your href:

```
$("nav a[href='"+newHash+"']").addClass("link2currentpage");
```

Comment: @WillAndrew - No problem. Though, if it fixed the problem, then why mark another answer as *the answer*?

Comment: It fixed a different problem to the one I was asking but I'm still grateful!

Comment: @WillAndrew - OK, no worries. That I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You've got an error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://drue.co.uk/1site/index.html from frame with URL
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/GaoLU6zKaws?rel=0. Domains, protocols and
>   ports must match.

You cannot make cross-sites Ajax request in Javascript for safety reason.

You may use YouTube's API to add embedded players: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo