# Expanding list not moving container/footer

Tags: javascript, css, html, html-lists

I have a website you can find [here](http://drue.co.uk/1site/index.html), when expanding one of the list items, I can't figure out why the the entire height of the page isn't being modified (footer doesn't move with list expansion). Any ideas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#inside` div has an `height` property set. If you remove it, you'll get the behaviour you want.

**Edit**

It seems you're setting the `height` property via javascript in order to animate the div's `height`.

In this case, after animation's been completed, you could set the `height` to `auto`, so the `#inside` div will respect its children's `height` and expand correctly.

```js
$pageWrap.animate({
    height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
}, {
    complete: function(){
        $(this).css('height', 'auto');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! see above for reply

Comment: After animation's been completed you could set the #inside's height to auto.

Comment: Many thanks, that did the trick, check the changes at http://drue.co.uk/1site/index.html . One problem I found is that if the current address is .../index.html and not .../index.html#index.html then the problem still occurs, any ideas?

Comment: It's probably because of this line: `$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());` on your js file. Try to comment it or set it to `auto` too.

Answer (score 0):

One of your divs has a manual style on it:

```
<div id="inside" style="height: 367px;">
```

Remove / disable that and your page container resizes accordingly :)

Comment: Thanks understood, but as a result of the dynamic content loading, the page does not get re-sized when loading new content accordingly. I guess I need to change the following line but I'm not sure what to replace it with - height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"

Comment: Make it min-height instead of height and try that :)